# md-select arrow color change

Tags: html, css, vue.js

Can I somehow change arrow color for md-select from vue.js.

```
<md-input-container class="wid blueColor">
    <label>Aggregate</label>
    <md-select v-model="aggregate" class="blueColor">
      <md-option value="QUARTER_HOUR">15 min</md-option>
      <md-option value="HALF_HOUR">30 min</md-option>
      <md-option value="HOUR">1 hour</md-option>
      <md-option value="DAY">1 day</md-option>
    </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

[https://codepen.io/zupa10/pen/JWGKWK](http://codepen.io/zupa10/pen/JWGKWK)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dropdown's caret is being added via the `::after` property. You can change it's values in CSS using:

```
.md-select:after {
  /* CSS Properties Here */
}
```

As seen in [this CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MpGMve), you may have to increase the priority of the CSS selector. On a similar note - you should be able to use Google Chrome's Inspector to see the element in question:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

add this css

```
.md-select::after {
    color: red !important;
}
```